# How can I hide a method with a generic return type from WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, design-by-contract

I have this scenario (abridged):

```
[ServiceContract]
public class TokenProviderService : ITokenProvider
{
    private ITokenProvider TokenProvider { get; set; }

    // BK - WCF doesn't like generic returns, so I've used an intermediary method.
    public T GetTokenValue<T>(string tokenId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public string GetTokenValueAsString(string tokenId)
    {
        return TokenProvider.GetTokenValueAsString(tokenId);
    }       
}
```

Where the only reason I implement the typed `GetTokenValue` because of `ITokenProvider`, a 'cast in stone' contract[1] interface used by both WCF and non-WCF clients. I have no wish to expose this as a service operation, and instead I use `GetTokenValueAsString`, and deserialize the result in a client proxy, that also implements `ITokenProvider`.

Yet despite having no `OperationContract` attribute, `GetTokenValue` causes the following error when I start the WCF project or try to add a service reference to this class:

> Type 'T' cannot be exported as a schema type because it is an open
>   generic type.

Is there any way I can tell WCF to ignore this method?

[1] Not a WCF contract, but a more general design contract.

Comment: Your sample code work for me without any error. I am able to start WCF test client. And see only `GetTokenValueAsString`(VS2013, Framework 4.5). Actually I've got an idea. Can you share your config file? contract should be TokenProviderService , not ITokenProvider

Comment: Did you tried implementing the method with explicit interface implementation? (Not sure this helps, worth a try). Also what is `ITokenProvider`?

Comment: @Siram, `ItokenProvider` is just an interface, to the token provider. It should have no bearing on this issue. BTW, I did try an explicit implementation, with no effect. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Uriil The configured contract is TokenProviderService, not the interface.

Comment: What happens if you remove the generic return method? Does the service now start? From what I can see you've done nothing wrong

Comment: @TomRedfern, if I remove the generic return method, my service does not event compile. That is the entire reason for this question: How can I make WCF ignore that method while still honouring the interface.

Comment: WCF should already be ignoring the method, as it's not part of the interface definition. I was hoping, by asking you to remove it, to confirm that the behavior is indeed being caused by the presence of that method. If so then I'd have to re-evaluate what I understand about WCF.